# How to creat mesh on the cube's surface?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Now I'm trying to solve a PDE by FEM, and I need creat the 2D mesh on the cube's surface, the figrue below shows my idea.

[image]

Both the quadrilateral elements and triangle element are OK. I read the [Element Mesh Generation Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) but didn't find good way.

The field variable is not continuous when crossing the edges, so I want to use the standard FEM procedure rather than the built-in function to solve it, therefore I need to know every nodes' coordinates and the elements incidents, and then write the program by myself.

Besides, how can I get the coordinates of the nodes located at the edges if the mesh is created?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: By "edges", you mean the blue lines in your figure?

Comment: Yes, this is a problem of energy transfer, when the energy meet the "edge" it will partly reflected and partly transmission, so I need some special operation on the nodes located at the "edge".

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Cuboid[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0125];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

to make the mesh. For the second question, there is no direct way to extract the edges but using the "Methods" documented in [ElementMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html) found in the scope section this should not be impossible.

Comment: `ToElementMesh[Cuboid[]]` creates a 3D mesh. Use `ToBoundaryMesh[Cuboid[]]` to get the 2D surface mesh.